# Linq-to-SQL: Improve performance (RANK OVER PARTITION)

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

## Brief

I'm working on converting a SQL script into Linq. This script uses `RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY...`

When the Linq passes the procedure to SQL, however, I'm left with a strange result, which is causing an increased number of reads being made to the table and increasing query time when compared to a *simpler* version of the Linq or the original SQL.

I realize the duration results are *marginally* different, however, the idea is to use *Linq to SQL* where possible. I'm trying to optimize the generated *Linq to SQL* code to improve performance.

The average durations are based on 1000 iterations of each script below. They have been rounded to the closest multiple of 50.

**Note**: Average duration is in microseconds.

---

---

## Research

I've read the answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022672/when-does-compile-queries-of-linq-to-sql-improve-performance) post. I don't believe my query is particularly expensive as it's fairly simple and straightforward. It's creating a convoluted query, however, which shows worse performance.

---

---

## Code

### SQL

The SQL script can be written a couple of different ways, so I'll provide both ways I've successfully accomplished to write this script below. Both methods are principally the same thing. One uses a CTE, while the other uses a nested query.

#### Method 1 (CTE)

Reads: 2
Average Duration: 650

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME = '2017-09-20'

;WITH Currency AS (
    SELECT 
            CurrencyType,
            AsOfDate,
            ConvFactor,
            RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CurrencyType ORDER BY AsOfDate DESC) AS ConversionRank
        FROM CurrencyDtl
        WHERE AsOfDate <= @date
)

SELECT
        CurrencyType,
        AsOfDate,
        ConvFactor
    FROM Currency
    WHERE ConversionRank = 1
```

---

#### Method 2 (Nested query)

Reads: 2
Average Duration: 600

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME = '2017-09-20'

SELECT
        cd.CurrencyType,
        cd.AsOfDate,
        cd.ConvFactor
    FROM (
        SELECT 
                cd.CurrencyType,
                cd.AsOfDate,
                cd.ConvFactor,
                RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY cd.CurrencyType ORDER BY cd.AsOfDate DESC) AS ConversionRank
            FROM CurrencyDtl AS cd
            WHERE cd.AsOfDate <= @date
    ) AS cd
    WHERE cd.ConversionRank = 1
```

---

---

### Linq

#### Method 1

Problem: Doesn't actually return the values I need: The second Linq method does return the values I need but at a higher cost.

Reads: 6
Average Duration: 900

**Linq**

```
MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext();
Table<CurrencyDtl> CurrencyDtl = db.GetTable<CurrencyDtl>();

DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("2017-09-20", "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var q = (from cd in CurrencyDtl
         where cd.AsOfDate <= date
         group cd by cd.CurrencyType into grp
         select grp.OrderByDescending(g => g.AsOfDate).First());
```

**SQL** (Linq-generated)

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t3].[test], [t3].[CurrencyType], [t3].[AsOfDate], [t3].[ConvFactor], [t3].[CurrencyDtlKey]
FROM (
    SELECT [t0].[CurrencyType]
    FROM [dbo].[CurrencyDtl] AS [t0]
    WHERE [t0].[AsOfDate] <= @p0
    GROUP BY [t0].[CurrencyType]
    ) AS [t1]
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (1) 1 AS [test], [t2].[CurrencyType], [t2].[AsOfDate], [t2].[ConvFactor], [t2].[CurrencyDtlKey]
    FROM [dbo].[CurrencyDtl] AS [t2]
    WHERE ((([t1].[CurrencyType] IS NULL) AND ([t2].[CurrencyType] IS NULL)) OR (([t1].[CurrencyType] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t2].[CurrencyType] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t1].[CurrencyType] = [t2].[CurrencyType]))) AND ([t2].[AsOfDate] <= @p0)
    ORDER BY [t2].[AsOfDate] DESC
    ) AS [t3]
ORDER BY [t3].[AsOfDate] DESC',N'@p0 datetime',@p0='2017-09-20 00:00:00'
```

---

#### Method 2

Reads: 14
Average Duration: 1200

**Linq**

```
MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext();
Table<CurrencyDtl> CurrencyDtl = db.GetTable<CurrencyDtl>();

DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("2017-09-20", "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var q = (from cd in CurrencyDtl
         where cd.AsOfDate <= date
         group cd by cd.CurrencyType into grp
         let c = grp.OrderByDescending(g => g.AsOfDate).First()
         select new
         {
             c.CurrencyType,
             c.AsOfDate,
             c.ConvFactor
         });
```

**SQL** (Linq-generated)

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT (
    SELECT [t3].[CurrencyType]
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP (1) [t2].[CurrencyType]
        FROM [dbo].[CurrencyDtl] AS [t2]
        WHERE ((([t1].[CurrencyType] IS NULL) AND ([t2].[CurrencyType] IS NULL)) OR (([t1].[CurrencyType] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t2].[CurrencyType] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t1].[CurrencyType] = [t2].[CurrencyType]))) AND ([t2].[AsOfDate] <= @p0)
        ORDER BY [t2].[AsOfDate] DESC
        ) AS [t3]
    ) AS [CurrencyType], (
    SELECT [t5].[AsOfDate]
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP (1) [t4].[AsOfDate]
        FROM [dbo].[CurrencyDtl] AS [t4]
        WHERE ((([t1].[CurrencyType] IS NULL) AND ([t4].[CurrencyType] IS NULL)) OR (([t1].[CurrencyType] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t4].[CurrencyType] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t1].[CurrencyType] = [t4].[CurrencyType]))) AND ([t4].[AsOfDate] <= @p0)
        ORDER BY [t4].[AsOfDate] DESC
        ) AS [t5]
    ) AS [AsOfDate], (
    SELECT [t7].[ConvFactor]
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP (1) [t6].[ConvFactor]
        FROM [dbo].[CurrencyDtl] AS [t6]
        WHERE ((([t1].[CurrencyType] IS NULL) AND ([t6].[CurrencyType] IS NULL)) OR (([t1].[CurrencyType] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t6].[CurrencyType] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t1].[CurrencyType] = [t6].[CurrencyType]))) AND ([t6].[AsOfDate] <= @p0)
        ORDER BY [t6].[AsOfDate] DESC
        ) AS [t7]
    ) AS [ConvFactor]
FROM (
    SELECT [t0].[CurrencyType]
    FROM [dbo].[CurrencyDtl] AS [t0]
    WHERE [t0].[AsOfDate] <= @p0
    GROUP BY [t0].[CurrencyType]
    ) AS [t1]',N'@p0 datetime',@p0='2017-09-20 00:00:00'
```

---

---

## Questions

1. How can I reduce the duration of the Linq-gerenated query?
2. How can I reduce the number of reads performed by the Linq-generated query?
3. Why is my **Method 2** Linq-generated query so convoluted?
4. Do you have any tips going forward to improve performance of further Linq-generated queries?

*P.S. Thank you for taking the time to read this long and detailed post.*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Brief

To go ahead and answer my own question. You can select the rows you want in the grouping instead of doing it in the select. Using the `let` seems to create duplicate subqueries (at least for `RANK OVER PARTITION BY` simulations).

This method reduces duration but doesn't reduce reads. If anyone has a better solution I'd be more than happy to accept it, but for now, this seems to be the best method.

---

### Code

Reads: 6
Average Duration: 700

#### Linq

```
MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext();
Table<CurrencyDtl> CurrencyDtl = db.GetTable<CurrencyDtl>();

DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("2017-09-20", "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var q = (from cd in CurrencyDtl
         where cd.AsOfDate <= date
         group new { cd.CurrencyType, cd.AsOfDate, cd.ConvFactor } by cd.CurrencyType into grp
         select grp.OrderByDescending(g => g.AsOfDate).First());
```

#### SQL

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t3].[test], [t3].[CurrencyType], [t3].[AsOfDate], [t3].[ConvFactor]
FROM (
    SELECT [t0].[CurrencyType]
    FROM [dbo].[CurrencyDtl] AS [t0]
    WHERE [t0].[AsOfDate] <= @p0
    GROUP BY [t0].[CurrencyType]
    ) AS [t1]
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (1) 1 AS [test], [t2].[CurrencyType], [t2].[AsOfDate], [t2].[ConvFactor]
    FROM [dbo].[CurrencyDtl] AS [t2]
    WHERE ((([t1].[CurrencyType] IS NULL) AND ([t2].[CurrencyType] IS NULL)) OR (([t1].[CurrencyType] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t2].[CurrencyType] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t1].[CurrencyType] = [t2].[CurrencyType]))) AND ([t2].[AsOfDate] <= @p0)
    ORDER BY [t2].[AsOfDate] DESC
    ) AS [t3]
ORDER BY [t3].[AsOfDate] DESC',N'@p0 datetime',@p0='2017-09-20 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are fighting random numbers. I tested it on 20M rows table. The linq queries took 2sec, but the rank aproach took 20sec.

I would recommend something different, if performance is so critical here. Just store the exchange rate for every currency for every day into the table. Then you just need to query rows for one day and that would be as efficient as possible. It would also give you the assurance that you work with valid value for that day and not some outdated one.

Comment: As much as I’d love to be able to do that, the database is part of a 3rd party application that we use. We’re currently building an application to extend its functionality. Believe me, I’d love to change 1000 things (actually probably the whole thing) about the 3rd party application; unfortunately it’s not currently possible. I’m stuck having to gather the most recent value regardless of it being outdated.